# Encontrar los dias faltantes en un periodo de tiempo

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo que encontrar dentro de un dataframe cuando un usuario se dio de alta o baja, para ello utilizo el siguiente codigo. Entendiendo que cuando el usuario aparece por primera vez fue una alta y la inversa para la baja del mismo.

```
from curses import erasechar
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': ['2022-08-29', '2022-08-30','2022-09-03', '2022-09-04','2022-09-05','2022-09-12'],'id': [20076,20076,20076,20076,20076,20076]})

df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
df = (df.set_index('Fecha')
      .reindex(pd.date_range('2022-08-29', '2022-10-01', freq='D'))
      .rename_axis(['Fecha'])
      .fillna(0)
      .reset_index())
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
print(df)
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta es como puedo llegar a este resultado final, mostrando solo los datos de cuando fue dado de alta y lo mismo para la baja pero no repetir dia por dia, ya que se entiende que solo se busca la fecha en donde fue dado de alta y la baja.
Teniendo como resultado final de acuerdo al ejemplo de arriba la siguiente salida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un gusto en saludar

Acá te muestro cómo enfoqué el resultado. Primero desde el frame principal creo una columna vacía tipo obj para volcar allí los resultados definitivos de ALTA y BAJA, filtrando sólo en la ocurrencia de casa fecha porque las demás fechas están vacías

```
df['Resultado'] = None
dff = df[df['id'] ==  20076]
```

esto me arroja un dataframe de este tipo

```
   Fecha       id           Resultado
0  2022-08-29  20076.0      None
1  2022-08-30  20076.0      None
5  2022-09-03  20076.0      None
6  2022-09-04  20076.0      None
7  2022-09-05  20076.0      None
14 2022-09-12  20076.0      None
```

Nota que los índices de ese frame filtrado es [0,1,5,6,7,14], pero para efectos de la lógica resetearemos esos indices a [0,1,2,3,4,5]

```
dff= dff.reset_index(drop=True)
dff['index']=dff.index
```

Entendiendo que según la segunda imágen donde sale la tabla de **resultados** la **FECHA** de ocurrencia más alta sería un "ALTA", entonces iteractúo con la paridad o imparidad del índice,por lógica los PARES son ALTAS y los IMPARES son BAJAS

```
for i in list(dff['index']):
  if dff.index[i] % 2 == 0:
       dff.iat[i,2] = 'ALTA'
  else:
       dff.iat[i,2] = 'BAJA'
```

El FOR anterior sería la lógica que volvará en la columna **RESULTADO** la alta y la baja

```
dff[['Fecha','id','Resultado']]


    Fecha       id      Resultado
0   2022-08-29  20076.0 ALTA
1   2022-08-30  20076.0 BAJA
2   2022-09-03  20076.0 ALTA
3   2022-09-04  20076.0 BAJA
4   2022-09-05  20076.0 ALTA
5   2022-09-12  20076.0 BAJA
```

Espero haber contrubuido a la solución.. saludos